# The effect of boundedness of $f''$ for a positive differentiable function in limit at infinity.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a positive differentiable function on $(0,\infty)$, Then prove that

i. If $f'$ is continuous with $f' \leq 0$ and $f''$ is bounded, Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f'(x)=0$.

ii. $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\left (\frac{f(x+\epsilon x)}{f(x)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$ exists and non -zero for any $x \in (0,\infty)$.

How can we show the boundedness of $f''$ implies $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f'(x)=0$ for a non-increasing function?

What is the role of continuity of $f'$, meanwhile the boundedness of $f''$ implies $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Some hints: $f$ is positive and decreasing, so that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists. Use Taylor's theorem in the form $f(x+h)-f(h)  = hf'(x) + \frac 12 h^2 f''(c)$ and the boundedness of $f''$ to show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x) = 0$. – (ii) is easy: Take the logarithm and “recognize” the expression as a differential quotient.

Comment: You should assume $f$ is twice differentiable in the first sentence.